# What is the SQL Server Profiler NtUsername variable in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, ms-access, sql-server-profiler

SQL Server Profiler shows NtUsername when I run a trace on my MS Access 2003 app with linked tables. The MS Access app connects through a default username: Bogus. But when I run the trace it shows the Windows Username domain\username.

How do I grab the Windows Username so that I can use it in a trigger just like it shows in the Profiler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SUSER_NAME()` will return `'dom\user'` for the executing windows authenticated user or just `'username'` for an sql authenticated user.

Comment: In his case he is seeing the `domain\user` account in profiler even though the app is connecting to SQL Server using sql auth (I know this from a related question of his). I couldn't explain it either; I haven't seen this scenario.

Comment: Interesting. The SUSER_SNAME() works for some users and not for others. For some it shows dom\user other is shows BOGUS.